# Screen times out in i3 WM

Tags: i3-wm

I love i3 for obvious reasons (light, maxing screen size, ability to customize). However, my screen times out after five minutes of inactivity. I would like to turn this off, how?

I've got i3 on ubuntu 14.04 and 15.10.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

X.org has some basic screen saver functionality as well as energy saving features. Most likely either or both are responsible for the described behavior.

The settings for both can be viewed and changed with the `xset` tool (from the `x11-xserver-utils` package). `xset q` displays the current settings in the sections *Screen Saver* and *DPMS (Energy Star)*.

You can disable the screen saver feature with:

```
xset s off
```

The power saving feature can be turned off with

```
xset -dpms
```

With these settings the screen should no longer turn off or blank automatically until you reboot your machine.

---

If your main concern is that 5 minutes are to short, you can also just raise the limits for that. To enable the screen saver only after 15 minutes (900 seconds) idle time, set the timeout accordingly with

```
xset s 900
```

To turn off the monitor after 20 minutes of idling run

```
xset dpms 0 0 1200
```

The two `0` values disable *standby* and *suspend* respectively, while `1200` sets the timeout for *off* to 20 minutes. (I usually do not use *standby* or *suspend* because there seems to be no difference between the three modes on modern TFT-displays.) Setting these values also enables *DPMS*, so you do not need to explicitly run `xset +dpms`.

Comment: Do these settings persist after a reboot? I'd like to turn off power saving until I next reboot.

Comment: No, settings made with `xset` are usually not persistent. It might be possible that some other tool reads out the values from `xset` and reloads them on reboot, but I never encountered any such tool myself. If you *want* to make those changes permanent, you can either make some equivalent settings in the `xorg.conf` or just run `xset` from some X auto start script.

Comment: If you're running i3 (like in the OP) you can add commands to be auto-run into `~/.i3/config`, like so: `exec xset dpms 0 0 1200`. If you want the command to also be run if you only restart i3, use `exec_always` instead of `exec`.

Comment: I tried the commands above, but the screen still turns off after 30 mins. Is there some other mechanism that may be responsible?

Comment: works for me for i3.

Answer (score 1):

xset did not work for me.

what did work was modifying

```
~/.xscreensaver
```

and changing timeout to something very large like

```
timeout:    9:00:00
```

and then after saving the file - not sure if it's necessary, but to be sure I do in terminal:

```
xscreensaver-command --restart
```

and then you can always change it back later.